# raspberry-pi: how to configure hc-05

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

i would like to connect my android phone to my raspberry trought bluetooth connection. i've plugged a hc-05 module into my raspberry, and it works. i can read some device info from my smartphone and if i modify the files

/boot/cmdline.txt
/etc/inittab

for using bluetooth terminal access by smartphone it works.
if i use :

- `hcitool dev` i get `Devices:`
- `/etc/init.dbluetooth status` i get `[ ok ] bluetooth is running.`

i can't reach the bluetooth module with python script. for example :

```
from bluetooth import *

targetName="Madlollo"
targetAddress=None
port=2
def searchService():
    mServices=find_service(uuid="00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
    if len(mServices)==0:
        print"can't find available service"
    else:
        first_match=mServices[0]
        mPort=first_match["port"]
        mName=first_match["name"]
        mHost=first_match["host"]
        print"Discovered %s on %s at port %s",(name,host,port)

def searchPhone():
    global targetAddress
    nearbyDevices=discover_devices()
    for address in nearbyDevices:
        if targetName==lookup_name(address):
            targetAddress=address
            break
    if targetAddress is not None:
        print"found target Phone with address: ", targetAddress
    else:
        print"can't find target Phone"

def sendMsg(msg):
    sock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
    sock.connect((targetAddress,port))
    a=sock.send(msg)
    if(a>0):
        print"inviati %d byte" %a
    sock.close()

def readData():
    server_sock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
    #rport=get_available_port(RFCOMM)
    rport=0
    server_sock.bind(("",rport))
    server_sock.listen(1)
    print"listening on port %d" %rport
    #advertise_service(server_sock,"00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
    client_sock,address=server_sock.accept()
    data=client_sock.recv(1024)
    print"received[$s]"%data
    client_sock.close()
    server_sock.close()
```

and if i use `searchPhone()` or `searchService()` i get the following error:

```
File "blue.py", line 52, in <module>
    searchService()
File "blue.py", line 7, in searchService
    mServices=find_service(uuid="00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 186, in find_service
    devices = discover_devices ()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 17, in discover_devices
    sock = _gethcisock ()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 226, in _gethcisock
    raise BluetoothError ("error accessing bluetooth device")
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: error accessing bluetooth device
```

I need to get the bluetooth module reachable from hcitool.
Anyone have an idea to how control the hc-05 with raspberry?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but it probably needs a password to the HC-05 module.
https://myraspberryandme.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/bluetooth-serial-communication-with-hc-05/

Basically, you need to provide the password (1234) of the HC-05 module before connecting.